# how to add class reference in jquery so li hover only work in my menu not everywhere

Tags: jquery

I am add the jquery hover effect in li in my menu bar but the page when found the anywhere li tag that's hover effect is working but i need only menu bar for hover effect my menu bar class is menu-toogle

```
 // insert slider
jQuery('ul').append('<div id="slider"></div>');

// initially reset
var left = jQuery('ul li:first-child a').parent().position().left;
var width = jQuery('ul li:first-child a').width();
jQuery('#slider').css({'left' : left, 'width' : width});

// sliding
jQuery('ul li a').hover(function(){

    var left = jQuery(this).parent().position().left;
    var width = jQuery(this).width();

    jQuery('#slider').stop().animate({
        'left' : left,`enter code here`
        'width' : width
    });
});
```

Comment: JavaScript is not JAVA, and tagging this with PHP makes little sense either - please try and tag _properly_. The first line of your code is doing wrong stuff already - `ul` can not have `div` as a child. And as for your actual question - well just be more specific with your selector then, where is the problem? Add whatever class you are referring to in the right position there …

Comment: you cannot append a div to a ul - that's invalid, but to answer your question, give the ul a class and target that - at the moment you target all ul

Comment: how to add class please give me a demo